# Remove a dot from a style!

Tags: theorems

I'm using the code below to create a theorem style. The style, however, leave a dot after the title in the title box. I want to remove that. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{boiboites}

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,
titleboxcolor = black]{theo}{Theorem}{anything}

\begin{document}
 \begin{theo}[Law of Large Numbers]
 Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an infinite sequence of i.i.d. variables with finite expected value. Then:
 $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{\textnormal{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}
     \mathbb{E} (X_1) .$$
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `boiboites` is not available in my system. I'm using TeX Live 2014.

Comment: @Manuel: How can share the style file here? You can get it from here btw => http://snouffy.free.fr/blog-en/index.php/post/2010/01/30/Nice-boxes-for-your-theorems-with-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the `boiboites.sty` style file and simply edit **line (57)**:

`(##1)}\textbf{.}}`

to be like this:

`(##1)}\textbf{}}`

without the **dot** between the curly brackets.

This should solve your question and you get the following:

[image]

Well, after reading other solutions, I think it is a better idea not to modify the `.sty` file since an update will affect your `.tex` file. According to the suggestion of Gonzalo Medina, the complete example could be modified as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{boiboites}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xpatchcmd{\newboxedtheorem}{\textbf{.}}{}{}{}

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=orange, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue!20,
titleboxcolor = black]{theo}{Theorem}{anything}

\begin{document}
 \begin{theo}[Law of Large Numbers]
 Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an infinite sequence of i.i.d. variables with finite expected value. Then:
 $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{\textnormal{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}
 \mathbb{E} (X_1) .$$
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Modifying a `.sty` file is not recommended: if you install an update to the package, you lose your changes.

Comment: @LatexQuest please, do *not* modify the style file. Instead, you can add the following lines to the preamble of your `.tex` file (without touching the `.sty` file): `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\newboxedtheorem}{\textbf{.}}{}{}{}`

Comment: I've temporarily down-voted this answer since modifying a `.sty` file is not recommended. I also provided a workaround to this in my previous comment, so if the answer is modified accordingly I'll gladly reverse the down-vote.

Comment: Thanks for adding the version without modifications to the `.sty`. As promised, I reversed my down-vote.